# Illustrator - Problem with Vector Graphics when I resize it

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I got this problem when I shrink an object that I have created by minus a text (appearance expanded) from an ellipse.

[image]

Scaling to a smaller size

[image]

The error happened

This makes me confused. All the path is distorted. I have checked all the things before ask you guys about this. Before scaling, everything is okay and no distortion has been found, I have changed to the Outline mode and nothing is strange.

Thanks if you can help me fix this <3
PS: I'm not a native English speaker so I think there will be some grammatical and spelling errors, sorry for that!

Comment: You have snap to pixels on?

Comment: Is this a scaling artefact from using GPU preview on your particular machine? Switch to CPU preview and see if it's still there. I couldn't quite understand if your exported image is affected or just the preview so please excuse if you've covered this already.

Comment: @joojaa do you mean "snap to point"? I'm using Illustrator CC 2013 Portable.

Comment: no snap to pixel is what i mean. There is no such thing as illustrator cc portable.

Comment: Oh than just add an outline ( stroke). If it won't let you than create a new one in the appearances panel. BTW your first example I cannot see anything.

Comment: thanks everyone, i fixed my problems. "Align to pixel grid" is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have too close anchors or overlaping ones. 
Or maybe it is just some bug of selection view and it is not affecting the real object. If you really do not see it in the outline mode(object deselected)than it is not important.
Bye

Comment: What distortion? That the 3 looks funny? That looks like scaling without scaling Stokes and effects.

Comment: @Webster, the object has no outline. See it at the bottom of tools panel.

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely bizarre. I was not able to duplicate this problem. I used Exclude (Minus Front) and Divide on small and large-scale versions, and both had the same result when I enlarged it or shrunk it - no problems, and very smooth output. I also noticed that in your screenshot, there appear to be blue paths elsewhere in the document and wonder if this was part of your original Exclude that has gone wrong. Since this is a very simple design, I would suggest you recreate it at the desired size by zooming in.

[image]